# Getting Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware - Authentication failed

Tags: sitecore-commerce, authentication, azure-ad

While using **Azure AD B2C** as an external identity provider we are getting **Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware - Authentication failed** error in our security report. Anyone have any idea on this why we are getting this??

Comment: Can you provide any additional context or detail around the authentication failure that you are getting?  It would also be helpful for the community to understand how you've configured Sitecore Identity to accept claims from Azure AD in order to help provide assistance or answer the question.

Comment: Did you check this article? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884965/validate-oauth-bearer-token-iissuersecuritytokenprovider-missing-in-microsoft-o

Comment: Getting this error:
Exception: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException
Message: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys: '[PII is hidden]', 
token: '[PII is hidden]'.
Source: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt